# How to congifure Visual Studio 2017 android emulator to work on localhost

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.forms to consume an api. For that I have added a web project in my solution and I am using api's in its controller to manipulate data.

Firstly I deployed it on the Windows emulator all worked fine.

But when U deployed the same on Android, I get various exceptions such as-

> System.Net.WebException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:53865

or:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I have tried solution such giving it internet permission, using ip address my system and using 10.2.2.2 but i am unable to run the application.

Below is the code for login it is giving Jsonreader exception-

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username",username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","password")
        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://192.168.0.0:53865/Token");
        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var jwt = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var jwtDynamic = new JObject();
        jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jwt);

        //dynamic jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jwt);

        var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");
        var accessExpires = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>(".expires");
        Settings.AccessTokenExpiration = accessExpires;

        Debug.WriteLine(jwt);

        return accessToken;
}
```

This is the Login - it is throwing a `System.Net.Web.Exception` :

```
public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmpassword)
{
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var model = new RegisterBindingModel()
        {
            Email = email,
            Password = password,
            ConfirmPassword = confirmpassword
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);

        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:53865/api/Account/Register", content);
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Configure your API URL to run on 127.0.0.1 instead of a localhost:

```html
// .NET Core Web.Api example
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .UseStartup()
 .UseUrls(“http://127.0.0.1:5001“)
 .Build();
```

2. Configure your Xamarin.Forms API consumer to have a conditional URL base:

```html
 string apiUrl = null;
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    apiUrl = “http://10.0.2.2:5001/api“;
    else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    apiUrl = “http://localhost:5001/api“;
    else
    throw new UnsupportedPlatformException();
```

The problem with Android emulator is that it maps 10.0.2.2 to 127.0.0.1, not to localhost. However, the iOS Simulator uses the host machine network.

That should be it!

Comment: Where should be public static IwebHost block be placed